# How to make phpDoc comments visible in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc

I wonder how I can make PHPDoc-comments visible in Eclipse on a project-wide basis. For the moment, it only works in the current, open file.

It would be super to be able to check out all the @params and descriptions that I have put in before each function, outside the function's own file.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already documented your code elements via docblocks, then when you *use* those elements in your code, the hover popups feature of Eclipse will indeed show you what's in their docblocks.  This doesn't require you to have the other file open, e.g. writing code in test.php that uses class Foo from foo.php... you're not required to have foo.php open in the editor in order for your Foo object in test.php to have hover popup docblock info visible.

If such hover popups are not showing docblock info to you, then you might need to revisit your buildpath/includepath settings in your PHP project, particularly if the elements you're trying to use are actually defined in another *project* than the one you're working in.